# Is there a Python templating system that can inject method calls?

Tags: python

Need a Python templating engine that can make method calls from a module, rather than get static dict values.

I'm porting some code from Perl over to Python. In the original code,
I passed a blessed hash object to Template Toolkit to format output.
When you invoke a value like this in the template...

```
[% name %]
```

...it would call the dynamic object method...

```
$feature->name()
```

Can someone recommend a robust templating system that follows the same
dev pattern?  Most appear to expect a dict with a pre-populated set of
static values.  Instead, I want to pass the template an instantiated
module, using a pattern like this:

```
ft = Feature()                                                              
...                                                                         
output = runSomeTemplatingEngine(templateString, ft)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but you can try using ```getattr()``` if you have the method name in a string. For example, if you have an object called ```feature``` with a method ```name```, you can call it with ```getattr(feature, "name")()```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)

Answer (score 0):

In said dictionary you can easily pass an object and access it's methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Qree](https://github.com/polydojo/qree) (read "Curie"). It relies on `exec()` & `eval()`, and hence supports all language features.

In a Qree template, you can import modules, assign variables, call functions, etc. You can do everything.

**Caution:** As Qree uses `eval()`, it should **NOT** be used to render untrusted templates.

Note: I'm Qree's author.